# Mongo - Merge Duplicate Entries In A Collection And Remove Old Entries

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to migrate an old database that reads from millions of CSV files to Mongodb. The old database has millions of entries and essentially what I want is for the new database to have these three fields - Contact Name, Email & Contact Numbers. I will be reading this information in from hundreds of different CSV files with various formats. I have written a python script that will extract the information from these files and put them in a new csv file in the following layout:

Email:Name:Contact_No

The issue that I am having is that some of these emails are present in multiple CSV files and may have multiple different contact numbers. When I import these CSV files using the mongoimport command there may be multiple entries for the same email.

I am trying to create one entry in the master collection that will be formatted as follows:

```html
{
  Email:samplemail@xxx.com
  Name: John Doe
  Phone: [
           12345678,
           23456789,
           12354677,
         ]

}
```

I am quiet new to Mongo so I was hoping someone with a bit more insight and experience would be able to suggest an alternative solution to my current implementation.

*********************  CURRENT IMPLEMENTATION *************************

At the moment I import the CSV files to the Database by following these 4 steps.

1. Import the database using the mongo import command

```html
mongoimport -d Master_Contacts -c Master_Collection --type csv --file '/root/Documents/log.csv' --columnsHaveTypes --fields "Email.string(),Name.string(),Number.string()" --numInsertionWorkers 8
```

This appears to work fine. I can import approximately 1.6 million entries in about 2 mins with only 8GB of ram allocated.

2. Remove Duplicates

My current implementation of removing duplicates is as follows. I use the aggregate function to find multiple entries for the same email-> find all entries with that email and associated numbers and then output these to a new collection called duplicates using the following command:

```html
db.Master_Collection.aggregate([{$group: {_id: {email:"$email"},count: { "$sum":1 },number:{$addToSet:"$number"}}},{ $match: {count: { "$gt": 1 }}}, {$out:"duplicates"}],{allowDiskUse:true})
```

I am then removing these results from the original collection using the following command:

```html
db.Master_Collection.aggregate([{$group: {_id: {email:"$email"},count: { "$sum":1 },number:{$addToSet:"$number"}}},{ $match: {count: { "$gt": 1 }}}],{allowDiskUse:true}).forEach(function(doc){print(db.Master_Collection.remove({"email":doc._id.email}))});
```

3. Insert All Entries in Duplicate Collection Back Into Original Collection

I then again loop over the duplicates collection and insert all the entries into the master collection. However this seems to be highly inefficient and time consuming.

Would anyone please be able to provide suggestions or alternative solution.

Thanks in advance guys

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you aggregate the duplicates prior to insert into the destination table. You could do this in your Python script by, in memory preferably, collecting the duplicate contact info and storing it in the appropriate entry in a dictionary.

Then bulk insert your dictionary.

These fewer steps and fewer I/O operations should give you want you want with better performance.

Comment: I tried that. Took substantially longer. Plus multiple people may be uploading these files further down the line. So ideally I need it sanitized server side